# How docker enable ssh connection

Tags: bash, docker, ssh

guys. I wanna set an ssh connection for my docker. Here are my steps.
My information:

```
Ubuntu:
```

1. pull docker

   ```sh
   docker pull citybrainchallenge/cbengine:0.1.1
   ```
2. go into the container, steps 2-5 are executed in the docker

   ```sh
   docker run -it citybrainchallenge/cbengine:0.1.1 bash
   ```
3. install dependencies

   ```sh
   apt-get update
   apt-get install passwd openssl openssh-server openssh-clients
   ```
4. change password

   ```sh
   passwd
   ```
5. set the configuration, remove `#`

   ```sh
   vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```

   ```
   PubkeyAuthentication yes 
   PermitRootLogin yes 
   Port 22
   ```
6. save the container

   1. commit to a new container

   ```
   docker ps # check the container id 
   docker commit container_id new_image_id(I set: citybrainchallenge/cbengine:2.2)
   ```
7. run the new container and test it

   ```
   docker run -it citybrainchallenge/cbengine:2.2 bash
   ```

   In the container, restart ssh

   ```
   service restart ssh 
   service --status-all # check ssh is +
   ```
8. open a new terminal, Test its connection

   ```
   docker ps 
   docker port container_id 22
   ```

   However, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running the container can you pass port forwarding argument and check if that is working docker run -p 22:22

Comment: please add code fences for the command `` - surround them with backticks (`) - normally found to the left of 1 in the number row

Comment: I am so sorry. Now I am trying to connect the docker ssh in my mac, where the docker is in the Ubuntu. I am trying to connect the docker with `ssh root@my_ip -p 6666`. I can not connect it.